# How to get number of duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql table **"DemoTable"** (id -> auto increment)

```
id   subject_id  subject_name  question  exams
1        3         sub3         ques1    e1,e4
2        3         sub3         ques2    e1
3        2         sub2         ques3    e1
4        2         sub2         ques4    e3,e5
```

**What I want is following output with this where clause** - `where exams like '%e1%'`

```
subject_id  subject_name  number_of_questions
    3         sub3         2
    2         sub2         1
```

At present, I am using two separate queries -

**To get list of subject names** -

```
Select Distinct subject_id, subject_name from DemoTable where exams like '%e1%'
```

and

**To get number of questions each subject has** -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM DemoTable where subject_id=$subject_id
```

But For my work, **i need a single query doing both the work,  as I mentioned above**.
How to do that?

**Edit - 1. As mentioned by "juergen d" in his answer** -

```
SELECT subject_id, subject_name, COUNT(distinct question) as questions_count 
FROM DemoTable 
where find_in_set('e1', exams) > 0
group by subject_id, subject_name
```

In this query `find_in_set('e1', exams) > 0` works, but only as `exams='e1'` NOT `exams like '%e1%'` which is my case.

**Any way to use `like` in `find_in_set`**?

Thanks. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT subject_id, subject_name, COUNT(distinct question) as questions_count 
FROM DemoTable 
where find_in_set('e1', exams) > 0
group by subject_id, subject_name
```

Comment: `find_in_set('e1', exams) > 0` works only if `exams = 'e1'` doesn't work if `exams like '%e1%'`
I even tried `find_in_set('%e1%', exams) > 0` but no luck.
How to get values for `like` too?

Comment: I am not sure whazt you try to do if that function does not work for you. Please add more example data and expected output

Comment: What i want to say is, the query you suggested works perfect only when value of string in `find_in_set(string, column_name)` is exactly equal, as you put it `find_in_set('e1',exams)`. 

**But in my case, column `exams` has multiple strings** (see the table structure above, `exams` has `e1,e4`). So I need to use `like`, so that query can include the row which has value `e1,e4` in column 'exams'. `find_in_set('e1',exams)` include rows which has only `e1` in exams `column` and dont include which has multiple values e.g. `e1,e4`Hope I am clear this time.

Comment: [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) does **exactly** what you want. Try it again. If it does not work then your example data is different from your real data.

Comment: i thought you went offline, so i asked new question with its exact behavior, please check this - [Link of new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207491/). sorry for the separate question.

Comment: I recreated everything, its working like you said. don't know where i was wrong previously.