# How to use find_in_set(value, column) with like %% values

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql table **"DemoTable"** (id -> auto increment)

```
id   subject_id  subject_name  question  exams
1        3         sub3         ques1    e1,e4
2        3         sub3         ques2    e1
3        2         sub2         ques3    e1
4        2         sub2         ques4    e3,e5
```

**What I want is following output with this where case** - `where exams like '%e1%'`

```
subject_id  subject_name  number_of_questions
    3         sub3         2
    2         sub2         1
```

with the help of Stackoverflow user `juergen d`, I used this query -

```
SELECT subject_id, subject_name, COUNT(distinct question) as questions_count 
FROM DemoTable 
where find_in_set('e1', exams) > 0
group by subject_id, subject_name
```

But, the problem with this query is it outputs as -

```
subject_id  subject_name  questions_count 
    3         sub3         1
    2         sub2         1
```

Which means, it only counts the rows `where exams = 'e1'`, therefore it didn't include first row `where exams = 'e1,e4'` [which gets included in normal cases by `where exams like '%e1%'`]

What query should be used to get desired output?

Thanks. Regards,

Comment: Juergen's answer should be correct on the data you have provided in the query.

Comment: Easy. Redesign your schema.

Answer (score 2):

Juergen's answer should be correct.  And, in fact, it should be better than this version:

```
SELECT subject_id, subject_name, COUNT(distinct question) as questions_count 
FROM DemoTable 
where exams like '%e1%'
group by subject_id, subject_name;
```

The advantage is that his version will not confuse `e10` and `e1` when searching for `e1`.  I suspect the data in your question and on your site is different.  You should try setting up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I recreated everything, its working like Juergen said. don't know where i was wrong previously. And thanks for the explanation of disadvantage of using `like` in this query.